# Missing Mapbox GL styles in Github pages react app

Tags: reactjs, github-pages, mapbox-gl-js, react-map-gl

I have created a GitHub pages app which hosts a React app. Within this app, I have 2 instances of Mapbox maps using [react-map-gl](https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/), and some styles are missing when deployed on GitHub pages.

Locally, all styles load properly and the map looks great. However, once deployed *some* styles are missing, not all.

- My custom styles don't load (although they have been made public)
- `mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9` loads fine
- `mapbox://styles/mapbox/outdoors-v12` fails to load
- All terrain is missing

The two maps I declare are as follows

1. Globe

```
<Map
  initialViewState={{
    longitude: -100,
    latitude: 40,
    zoom: 1,
  }}
  terrain={{ source: "mapbox-dem", exaggeration: 1.5 }}
  mapboxAccessToken={
    "redacted"
  }
  style={{ width: "100%", height: 480 }}
  mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/outdoors-v12"
>
  <Source
    id="mapbox-dem"
    type="raster-dem"
    url="mapbox://mapbox.mapbox-terrain-dem-v1"
    tileSize={512}
    maxzoom={14}
  />
</Map>
```

2. 3d map

```
<Map
  initialViewState={{
    longitude: longitude,
    latitude: latitude,
    zoom: 14,
    bearing: 80,
    pitch: 80,
  }}
  maxPitch={85}
  terrain={{ source: "mapbox-dem", exaggeration: 1.5 }}
  mapboxAccessToken="redacted"
  style={{ width: "100%", height: "100vh" }}
  mapStyle={"mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9"}
>
  <Source
    id="mapbox-dem"
    type="raster-dem"
    url="mapbox://mapbox.mapbox-terrain-dem-v1"
    tileSize={512}
    maxzoom={14}
  />
  <MapMarker
    fixed
    closeButton
    markerName={name}
    latitude={latitude}
    longitude={longitude}
  />
  <Layer {...skyLayer} />
</Map>
```

Locally I see:
[image]

[image]

VS deployed on GitHub pages:
[image]

[image]

#### Tokens

The same tokens are used in deployment as locally. I've tried with the default public token, a custom token with only certain domains allowed, etc. All the same no matter what I try.

Anyone have an idea what I may be missing? I feel like this is a GitHub pages limitation, but at the same time some styling loads (e.g. satellite-v9, but not 3d or outdoors-v12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue - I am using `create-react-app` for this React app, and I had to configure the WebPack transpiling for mapbox as detailed in their documentation:
[Transpiling | MapBox Installation](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/guides/install/#transpiling)

I added the following to my package.json:

```json
"browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all",
      "not safari < 10",
      "not chrome < 51",
      "not android < 5",
      "not ie < 12"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
```

So finally not a GitHub Pages limitation, just an issue with the bundling which was hidden in the `create-react-app` scripts :)